# Pre-fetching 3rd party pages via iframes (for browser caching)

Tags: caching, iframe, browser, httpwebrequest

I send users to various third party sites which have divergent response times. When a site is slow, it really kills user experience.

Before a user clicks out to a third party site, they browse on a page which has a one-to-one relationship with the third party site's page.

I was thinking about opening a 1px iframe on my page, which would (in theory) cache assets from the third party site in the user's browser.

Does that sound interesting?  Would it work from a browser caching standpoint (I understand it's dependent on the 3rd party site's browser caching directives).   I also understand that it would be an ambiguous internet practice.

Thanks, 
Ben